# What symmetry has to be broken to result in the hyperfine structure splitting?

Tags: atomic-physics, symmetry-breaking

In Quantum Mechanics, symmetry operators $\mathcal{S}$ are associated with degeneracies if the Hamiltonian $H$ is conserved under the symmetry operation in question

$$\mathcal{S}^{\dagger}H\mathcal{S} = H. \tag{1}$$

This implies that $[G,H]=0$, where $G$ is the generator of $\mathcal{S}$, which in turn means that $G$ and $H$ have simultaneous eigenstates. If $H$ is changed such that Eq. $(1)$ is no longer valid, then the degeneracy is lifted.

Now, the hyperfine structure in atoms arises from the interaction of spin of the angular momentum of electrons $\mathbf{J}$ with the spin of the nucleus $\mathbf{I}$, which leads to the splitting of energy levels. What symmetry is broken when this interaction is accounted for in $H$ that lifts this degenercy? Knowing that angular momenta are generators of rotations, my initial thought is to say that some sort of rotational symmetry is broken here, but I can't see how.

Comment: Write down the interaction term. Is **J** conserved? Is **I**? Review all quantum numbers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfine_structure). Which ones are good, and which bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\mathbf{J}$ is the total (i.e. orbital + spin) angular momentum
  of the electrons, without the nuclear spin.
  The operator $\mathbf{J}$ generates the transformations
  $$U_e(\boldsymbol\phi)=\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\boldsymbol{\phi}\cdot\mathbf{J}\right)$$
  where $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ denotes the rotation axis and angle.
  Such a transformation rotates the electrons (orbitals and spins)
  without rotating the nucleus.
  $\mathbf{J}$ is not conserved, and hence (due to Noether's theorem)
  $U_e(\boldsymbol{\phi})$ is not a symmetry transformation.
  Or in other words: rotating only the electrons is a broken symmetry.
- $\mathbf{I}$ is the nuclear spin, without the electrons' angular momentum.
  The operator $\mathbf{I}$ generates the transformations
  $$U_n(\boldsymbol{\phi})=\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\boldsymbol{\phi}\cdot\mathbf{I}\right)$$
  where $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ denotes the rotation axis and angle.
  Such a transformation rotates the nucleus, without rotating the electrons.
  $\mathbf{I}$ is not conserved, and hence (due to Noether's theorem)
  $U_n(\boldsymbol{\phi})$ is not a symmetry transformation.
  Or in other words: rotating only the nucleus is a broken symmetry.
- On the other hand:
  $\mathbf{J}+\mathbf{I}$ (the total angular momentum of electrons and nucleus)
  is conserved. And therefore the transformations generated by it
  $$U_{e+n}(\boldsymbol{\phi})=\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\boldsymbol{\phi}\cdot(\mathbf{J}+\mathbf{I})\right)$$
  (rotating electrons and nucleus together) are symmetry transformations.